# Converting list into agents in foreach loop

Tags: foreach, netlogo

Here is a fraction of code that cause trouble.

```
to update-trustt
  let rank-tvmratio sort-on [tvmratio] turtles
  foreach rank-tvmratio tvmratio -> ask rank-tvmratio [set trustt (trustt + tvmratio)]
end
```

In this code, `"rank-tvmratio"` is supposed to bring list which looks like :
[(turtle 56) (turtle 23) ... (turtle 9)]

What I want to do is to make each of those turtles to update `"trustt"` variable 
respectively, which is written in the 3rd line.

Following Bryan's advice I inserted `"->"` and specified "who" is doing "what".

Still, there's a new error message `"Nothing name -> has been defined"`

How can I solve this problem? I need your wise advice.

(Actually variable `tvmratio` is coming from program R, using RNetLogo package. Is that have something to do with this?)

Thank you

Comment: Your `foreach` syntax is quite wrong.  What version of NetLogo are you using?

Comment: I use the latest version 6.0.1, how can i fix the syntax?

Comment: See the docs.
Is `trustt` a turtle variable?  What do you want it to be after this update.  The code is too wrong to tell.

Comment: It says foreach list command in the docs, so I thought there could be no problem. What I intended was for the each agent listed in the list, change(or update)trustt variable. In the code above turtle-own trustt.

Comment: "foreach" command can only handle number type of input" is false, `foreach` works with any list.

Comment: But can it interpret above list as an agent in foreach loop?

Comment: @HannahLee A list can contain agents; no problem.  You need to read the docs more carefully. And, see my questions above.

Comment: @HannahLee If you are having trouble with the docs, try this tutorial:
https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/notes/netlogo-intro.xhtml#iterating-over-a-list-with-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably want you're looking for:

```
to update-trustt
  let rank-tvmratio sort-on [tvmratio] turtles
  foreach rank-tvmratio [ t ->
    ask t [
      set trustt (trustt + rank-tvmratio)
    ]
  ]
end
```

There was a couple problems with your code. First, the command given to `foreach` needs to include an argument. You do this with the `->` syntax. The `t` (for turtle) before the `->` is the variable that each item in the list will be passed in as. Second, you need to explicitly ask `t` since `foreach`, unlike `ask`, doesn't have the agents run the command, it just runs the command with the items passed in one at a time as the argument to the command.

Comment: Sorry and thank you, Bryan . Still that solution doesn't fix the exisiting problem. I don't know why either. So I couldn't accept it as a answer. Is there any other way to view this?

Comment: Ah, woops, I did have a typo in the above. There was an erroneous `]` at the end of the `set trustt` line. However, you shouldn't be getting `"Nothing name -> has been defined"`. Are you sure you're using 6.0.1?